# Forcing browser caching on custom controller / full page cache disables browser caching

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

I have a custom controller which should serve some more or less static HTML block, with this code:

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\HttpFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Entries implements HttpGetActionInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private Navigation           $navigation,
        private readonly PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        private readonly HttpFactory $httpResponseFactory
    )
    {
    }

    /**
     * Execute action based on request and return result
     *
     * @return ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
     * @throws NotFoundException
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        $categories = $this->navigation->getNavigation(5);

        $content = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(Template::class)
            ->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::html/header/topmenu/menu.phtml')
[...]
            ->toHtml();

        $response = $this->httpResponseFactory->create();
        $response->setContent($content);
        $response->setPublicHeaders(3600);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

setPublicHeader should set a max-age and force browser caching.

```
        $this->setHeader('pragma', 'cache', true);
        $this->setHeader('cache-control', 'public, max-age=' . $ttl . ', s-maxage=' . $ttl, true);
        $this->setHeader('expires', $this->getExpirationHeader('+' . $ttl . ' seconds'), true);
```

But it doesn't.

```
$ http -ph https://example.local/theme/menu/entries
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
```

Is this expected behavior, when the full page cache is on? I tried to debug and in Magento the headers seem to be overwritten, but did not fully understand what's happening here with the full page cache.

EDIT:

More debugging:

`\Magento\Framework\App\FrontController::processRequest` calls

```
$this->response->setNoCacheHeaders();
```

When reaching

`\Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin::addDebugHeaders`

Also cache control contains `max-age=0`

Much later `\Magento\PageCache\Model\Layout\LayoutPlugin::afterGenerateElements` sets the plugic header, because the layout is cacheable.

Then this code again sets no cache headers: `\Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel::process`

```
    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
    {
        if (preg_match('/public.*s-maxage=(\d+)/', $response->getHeader('Cache-Control')->getFieldValue(), $matches)) {
            $maxAge = $matches[1];
            $response->setNoCacheHeaders();  ### trying to comment out
            if (($response->getHttpResponseCode() == 200 || $response->getHttpResponseCode() == 404)
```

Which I don't understand, because it's actually matching for `public` which means "cacheable".

If I comment out this line in the above snipped, it would be cached - so literally the full page cache is disabling the browser cache.

So it boils down to this line:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/984630670aa9ffb711b3169f1c1a15ea5cc4f052/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php#L154

Why did the inventors put that here :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I now understand, why this line was put there:

s-maxage is for the shared cached, which is the FPC, see [Mozilla dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control?retiredLocale=de#s-maxage).

Unfortunately there seems currently no simple way to

- Cache in the FPC
- and additionally cache in the browser

That really is a pity.